# How to override a function in the wp_includes folder(blocks/search.php)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, search-form

I'm creating a WordPress theme and I want to change the HTML structure of the search widget block so as have some level of control. I was able to trace the block to a core WordPress file which has a function that handles the HTML structure for the search form: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/blocks/search.php#L15

How do I override this function from my functions.php in my theme so I can generate a different HTML structure for the search widget block?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: No need to override files. In WP, you can pretty much customize most things by using hooks: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/168087/modifying-the-default-search-widget

Comment: @M.Eriksson this solution works if the widget is using the function get_search_form. But that's not the case anymore. In WordPress 5.9, the search widget is a block and it has its own HTML structure which I'm trying to override right now

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://bastiaandewaele.medium.com/customize-existing-gutenberg-blocks-10c2f2429121

Comment: @Cray thanks. I read through and I tried to do the same by using WordPress Filter hooks. But for some reason, I don't know, it didn't work.